# Is NSA disclosure of CRYPT32 vulnerability a charitable public service?

Tags: cryptography, vulnerability, nsa

News coverage of this makes it sound like the NSA is mending fences and helping us all out, kindly and heroically.

I have nothing against the NSA but isn't it more likely an adversary has been exploiting the vulnerability and they are disclosing it to mitigate that entity's effectiveness?

Still a public service perhaps but without the warm and fuzzy feelings in the news.

Answer (score 1):

The mission of the NSA is both to help the USA. In some cases this might mean to keep a bug secret in order to use it against adversaries. In other cases keeping a bug secret means too much risk that USA companies and citizens are attacked by adversaries using this bug. Thus it is not about being nice or not but disclosing a bug or not is based on weighing the chances vs. the risks.